# How to reduce PDF file size for while generating PDF from chrome print option

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, pdf

I was created one web page using HTML/CSS.

The web page design for the table format and Table cell's having 20 images. The total image size is 4 MB.

I used Ctrl+P to save PDF file, The PDF file size is getting 12 MB.

How to reduce any PDF file without any tool. there is any other way to reduce like @print media query or HTML/CSS structure change?

Comment: You could reduce the bit-depth of the images and make use of indexed-images (ones with a palette) unless my memory's failing, power-of-two image sizes help also. Another thing is the font used. If you can use the (pdf)inbuilt fonts, you avoid the browser including an abridged copy of the relevant font-file.
Adobe's "PDF Reference" files might give you some useful pointers. E.g https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.7old.pdf

Comment: Ctrl + P is an interface for printing - use `@media print` rules in your CSS to set specific styles for printing. For example you can set lower resolution background images

Comment: yes I understood @media print but already images having lower resolution image

Example: https://codepen.io/itjayaprakash/full/MWPGzga

Comment: No i just added jspdf canvas libray  that one also now removed.  Then also getting 12mb. Please refer https://codepen.io/itjayaprakash/full/MWPGzga

Comment: This one https://free.keep.sh/CajrrDOgWOsKami2/printout_cleaned.pdf  i can accessible secod one not.

 It is download Just 2mb wow surprised. but you compressed my PDF using online tool. i am expecting via chrome print option to download maximum 5mb.

Comment: Thanks for Your effort. I see the big difference in both zip files. I noticed one think from folder files there are two difference(jpeg/PNG) file format. Each PNG image contain above 1MB i don't know. How it get generated PNG format. I used .jpeg file format only all the big pictures. And i used img resolution is 1280*960. White background remove mean not clear.  Can you guid me  you can see my  codepen link